# How to search and extract matched words from a different column in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a variable in a dataframe which has field name 'Destination'. This field contains destination/places (can be country, continent, multiple countires, cities, city, etc. or both). I have another dataframe which contains 3 columns continent_name, country_name, city_name, etc. I want to get new column having continent, country, city names by matching destination field with 2 dataframe columns.

Dataframe A:

```
+---------+------------------------------------+
|  Name   |            Destination             |
+---------+------------------------------------+
| Alex    | North America, Europe & France     |
| Mike    | Boston, London, Germany, Australia |
| Charlie | China, Europe, India, New York     |
| Lophy   | Antartica, UK, Europe, Delhi       |
+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Dataframe B:

```
---------------+-----------+----------+
|   Continent   |  Country  |   City   |
+---------------+-----------+----------+
| north america | france    | boston   |
| anatartica    | germany   | london   |
| europe        | australia | delhi    |
| XYZ           | china     | new york |
| ABC           | india     | RST      |
| PQR           | UK        | JKL      |
+---------------+-----------+----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|  Name   |       Continent       |      Country       |      City      |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| Alex    | North America, Europe | France             |                |
| Mike    | NA                    | Germany, Australia | Boston, London |
| Charlie | Europe                | China, India       | New York       |
| Lophy   | Antartica, Europe     | UK                 | Delhi          |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

First all continent name should be matched and stored in comma separated value in case of multiple matches then country names and then city names.

I went through multiple questions but couldn't get anything concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# data
d <- read.table(text = "Name Destination
Alex 'North America, Europe & France'
Mike 'Boston, London, Germany, Australia'
Charlie 'China, Europe, India, New York'
Lophy 'Antartica, UK, Europe, Delhi'",
                header = TRUE,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d$Destination <- gsub("&", ",", d$Destination)
d$Destination <- tolower(d$Destination)
d$Destination <- trimws(d$Destination)
d

d2 <- read.table(text = " Continent  Country City
'north america' france boston
anatartica  germany london
europe australia delhi
XYZ china 'new york' 
ABC india RST
PQR UK  JKK", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d2

# splits ..
check_fun <- function(a, b) {
  toString(intersect(trimws(strsplit(d$Destination[a], ",")[[1]], "both"), d2[[b]]))
}

want <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,
                              lapply(colnames(d2),
                                     function(x) {
                                       sapply(seq_along(d$Destination),
                                              function(y) {
                                                check_fun(y, x)
                                              }
                                              )
                                       })), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(want) <- colnames(d2)
want$Name <- d$Name
want                              

# Continent            Country           City    Name
# 1 north america, europe             france                   Alex
# 2                       germany, australia boston, london    Mike
# 3                europe       china, india       new york Charlie
# 4                europe                             delhi   Lophy
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to put both tables in long format and join them, then go back to wide format using the destination type :

```
library(tidyverse)
B2 <- B %>% 
  gather(type,lower_dest) %>%
  mutate_at("lower_dest", tolower)

A2 <- A %>% 
  separate_rows(Destination,sep="\\s*[,&]\\s*") %>%
  mutate(lower_dest = tolower(Destination))

left_join(A2, B2, by = "lower_dest") %>%
  group_by(Name, type) %>%
  summarize_at("Destination", paste,collapse=", ") %>%
  spread(type, Destination) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      Name           City             Continent            Country
# *   <chr>          <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>
# 1    Alex           <NA> North America, Europe             France
# 2 Charlie       New York                Europe       China, India
# 3   Lophy          Delhi     Antartica, Europe                 UK
# 4    Mike Boston, London                  <NA> Germany, Australia
```

**data**

```
A <-
  tribble(~Name   , ~Destination ,   
 'Alex'    , 'North America, Europe & France',     
 'Mike'    , 'Boston, London, Germany, Australia', 
 'Charlie' , 'China, Europe, India, New York', 
 'Lophy'   , 'Antartica, UK, Europe, Delhi')     


# anatartica typo corrected into antartica  
B <- tribble(~Continent, ~Country, ~City,
 'north america' , 'france'    , 'boston'   ,
 'antartica'    , 'germany'   , 'london'   ,
 'europe'        , 'australia' , 'delhi'    ,
 'XYZ'           , 'china'     , 'new york' ,
 'ABC'           , 'india'     , 'RST'      ,
 'PQR'           , 'UK'        , 'JKL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Several functions that will help you:

`tolower()` will put all your words to lower case so you have matches when there is a mix of capital letters. 
`str_split()` from `stringr` will allow you to separate your destinations by elements separated by commas

So first, you need to get a vector with all your destinations:

`destination_vector <-unique(unlist(strsplit(tolower(Destination), ",")))` will do. Because `strsplit` gives you a list, you need `unlist` to get a vector. `unique` will get delete duplicates if any.

Then, you need to check if any of your destinations is in Continent, Country or City:

`Continent[Continent %in% destination_vector]` will do. The same for country and city

Then, you can use `paste` with `sep=","` to join all using commas as separator.

Best!